# Redirects and Meta Description

Tags: redirect, metadata

I am currently redirecting a website to another new website. My question is does a redirect automatically move my metadata (titles, taglines, meta description, focus keyphrases) to the new site? or Do I have to manually copy and paste metadata to the new site?

Better put - do my rankings from the old site as a result of metadata automatically point to my new site upon redirecting?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look into using a specific kind of redirect, which is the `HTTP 301 redirect`. That status code means its a `permanent redirect`, and most search engines will recognize that and will help keep your SEO.

If you do a `HTTP 302 redirect`, this being known as a `temporary redirect`, will technically be considered a new URL in the eyes of a search engine.

So when you are testing you redirect, make sure you open up Chrome Dev Tools (F12) and click the network tab. Refresh the page and click the first row that appears in the table. It should specify the HTTP status code, most likely being 200 (status ok), (301/302) permanent/temporary redirect, (404) file not found, 500 (server error).

So essentially, make sure your redirect is using a **301 redirect**, if it is permanent of course!